# Check if a class is on classpath in IJavaProject

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, sgen

I got a IJavaProject and a class in fqnd: "com.example.urgs.ClassName".

How do I figure out if it is in the Project?

edit:

```
    String value = "com.example.xx.Generator";

    IJavaProject ijp = JavaCore.create(this.getProject(parameterValue));
    try {
        if(ijp.findType(value) == null){
            return error("Generator class does not exist.");
        }
    } catch (JavaModelException e) {
        // Stacktrace
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This works for me ;)

edit2: parameterValue can be anything thats in the workspace.

Comment: You aren't use stackoverflow correctly. You should never edit question to add the answer. It is ok to answer your own question, but you need to post it as an answer.

Comment: what is IJavaproject btw?

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the class with something like this `Class.forName("com.example.urgs.ClassName")`

If the class cannot be located throws `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: thx, but I allready tried that :)
Its not the actuall workspace where i want to search, its the runtime-workspace of the generated Eclipse-instance.